# Efficient Prime Number Generator in c++

Tags: c++, performance, primes

I am trying to make an efficient prime number calculator. I've seen ones that can go up to close to 1 trillion in right around 4 hours, however I left mine on overnight and didn't get anywhere near that. I am asking this to see if anyone here knows a more efficient way for me to get up to a really high number really quickly. I also want to see if my everything else is up to standard as this is only my "2nd year" (classes where you self teach) coding.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> primes;  //vector that will have all numbers in it
    primes.push_back(3);      //push back the first 2 primes (not 2 due to never checking % 2 numbers)
    primes.push_back(5);
    for (unsigned long long i = 7;; i += 2)  //loop controlling the number that will be output
    {
        for (int j = 0; i % primes[j] != 0; ++j)  //loop that "scrolls" through my vector
        {
            if (sqrt(i) <= primes[j])  //if the square root of the number you're outputting is lower than the number you're checking against
            {
                std::cout << i << std::endl;  //output
                primes.push_back(i);  
                break;
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you search for "Eratosthenes" on this site, you'll find quite a few examples of a method that's (considerably) faster.

Answer (score 7):

The `std::vector<>` is a dynamically sized container.  The allocation strategy is implementation dependent, but for sake of the argument, assume the `.capacity()` of a `std::vector<>` starts off at 1 and doubles each time the vector's size exceeds the current capacity.  This capacity increase requires a reallocation of storage, and possibly a copying of the entire array contents to a new location.  If you are generating 1 trillion primes, you'll need 40 reallocations and will have done 1 trillion number copies over the course of the 40 reallocations.  This is wasting time.  If the operating system gets involved with virtual memory paging, you are going to suck up a lot more time.

This overhead can be eliminated by simply [`.reserve(size_type n)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/)-ing the expected size of the vector ahead of time.  With sufficient memory allocated to the vector upfront, no reallocations will occur, and no copies will occur.

---

```
    for (unsigned long long i = 7;; i += 2) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; i % primes[j] != 0; ++j)  
        {
            if (sqrt(i) <= primes[j]) 
            {
```

When `i` is a prime number or semi-prime number in the order of, say, one million, you are looping over all the prime numbers upto the square root of a million, to see if any of them can divide your current number.

How many different values will `sqrt(i)` evaluate to over those thousand iterations?  Or phrased another way, how many times are you computing the same square root?  You may want to move that `sqrt(i)` calculation out of the inner loop.

---

```
    for (unsigned long long i = 7;; i += 2)
```

If you let this loop run over night, or even over a fort-night, will this loop ever end?  No!  `i` will overflow the `long long` and become negative, and slowly increment back towards positive numbers and repeat.  Forever is not long enough.  Use, at the very least, `i > 0` as the loop test condition.

---

A `long long` has at least 64 bits. A `double` has only a 52 bit mantissa.  This means when you pass a large `long long` to `sqrt( )`, you will end up losing a few bits of precision, which can make your `sqrt()` return slightly the wrong value.  When you test `sqrt(i) <= primes[j]`, if `i` is greater than 2^52, and is a perfect square, you might return a value slightly less than the correct value and fail to test the last prime value, and erroneously declare the perfect square a prime number.

---

You are stuffing `long long` values into a `std:vector<int>` container.  After a while, they ain't gonna fit.

---

You are using `long long` for your prime number candidates, which means you expect to find some prime numbers above 2^31.

The Prime Number Theorem tells us the density of prime numbers in that range to be around 1/21.  Or, after testing numbers up to 21 billion, you should have found around 1 billion prime numbers.

Your prime number index `j` is declared as an `int`.  An `int` is only guaranteed to have 16 bits.  You would need at least a `long` to guarantee 32 bits.  But if you hope to find prime numbers up to 2^52, you have to expect to find 2^45 primes, which even exceeds a `long`.  Your `j` index should be a `long long` as well.

---

Finally, as mentioned in the comments, look at the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a peripheral advice

using `std::cout` is a **slow procedure**, you may do better with defining a temporary buffer of some significant size and use `std::cout` as soon as the buffer fills then reuse the buffer.